# React eventListener Type Issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image]

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleEscClose = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (e.key === 'Escape') changeVisibility();
    };

    if (isVisible) document.addEventListener('keydown', handleEscClose);
    return () => document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleEscClose);
  }, [changeVisibility, isVisible]);
```

This code detects esc when the modal is opened.
There is a type problem with handleEscClose , so what type should I add?

The following is an error message:

TS2769: No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(type: "keydown", listener: (this: Document, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(e: KeyboardEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Document, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any'.
Types of parameters 'e' and 'ev' are incompatible.
Type 'KeyboardEvent' is not assignable to type 'KeyboardEvent'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(e: KeyboardEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @slideshowp2 An error message has been marked. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `KeyboardEvent` type import from `react`. Instead, you should use the DOM event(comes from `lib.dom.d.ts`).  The event is DOM event **not** React [synthetic event](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html)

```
import React from 'react';
// import type { KeyboardEvent } from 'react';

const TestComp = () => {
    const handleEscClose = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {

    }
    React.useEffect(() => {
        document.addEventListener('keydown', handleEscClose)
    }, [])
}
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoAekrlEljhgE8wk4BvOAaSSYCMIKKABMAogDckAO3gBfONlwEi6GGXLk0EKQGd4AFSR6AwrjBwAvHAAUASksA+DuTiu4W3fAAWKKcIA2SKI6aMb+EDpsVtZIAFzcvAJCYpIy9hZO7BpucLIubsiqAHQArpGimJhIGNZ2js45OcIQaCUg0jBFKMIpHQAywHrSSFDW+ADWvM0A7lL4ADRwPn6BwaHhkbb5rrKLANoAuluyQA)

Comment: Wow, I've only used reaction events so far, but I didn't know that I'm using normal events Thank you so much Have a good day